# Копировать поля одной таблицы в другую с удалением первоначальной строки(sqlite)

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx

Необходимо выбрать строку в таблице по введенному id и значения ячеек скопировать в идентичную таблицу, а данную строку удалить. 
Пробовал сделать следующим образом:

```
@FXML
public void deleter(ActionEvent ae) {
    String sqld = "DELETE FROM teachers WHERE id = ?";
String cop = "SELECT fname, lname, email, predmet FROM teachers WHERE id =?"; String s2=" INSERT INTO uvolen (fname, lname, email, predmet) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

    try {

            Connection conn = dbConnection.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement pstmt1 = conn.prepareStatement(cop+s2);
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqld);
            pstmt1.setString(1, searchBox.getText());
            pstmt.setString(1, searchBox.getText());
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            pstmt1.executeUpdate();
            pstmt.close();
            pstmt1.close();
            loadTeacherData();


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Но возникает ошибка с INSERTOM:

> [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "INSERT": syntax error)

Возможно он не знает какие значения брать. Буду очень благодарен, если поможете.

Comment: Точка с запятой как разделитель запросов не нужна случайно( имею ввиду `cop+s2` )?

Comment: @AndreyM
Попробовал использовать разделитель ; — удаление происходит, но значения в другую таблицу не добавляются.
В консоли выводит: `Query returns results`

Comment: Я не очень понимаю, что в коде происходит: откуда возьмутся значения для `insert`? Если вы ожидаете, что они подставятся из `select` то это вроде так не работает( могу ошибаться) + удаление у вас происходит раньше и `select` ничего не вернёт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прислушавшись к ответам изменил код, он получился следующим:

```
@FXML
public void d(String i){
    String dd = "DELETE FROM teachers WHERE id = ?";

try {

    Connection c = dbConnection.getConnection();
         PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(dd);
    ps.setString(1, i);
           ps.executeUpdate();
            ps.close();
            c.close();
    loadTeacherData();

} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
}

@FXML
public void deleter(ActionEvent ae) {
   String a = "INSERT INTO uvolen (fname, lname, email, predmet) SELECT fname, lname, email, predmet FROM teachers WHERE id=?";
    try {
   Connection cn = dbConnection.getConnection();
   PreparedStatement pstmt = cn.prepareStatement(a);
   pstmt.setString(1, searchBox.getText());
   pstmt.executeUpdate();
pstmt.close();
d(searchBox.getText());
loadTeacherData();
cn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```